# apply_filters don't replace text at default widget

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to remove 'on' text string which shown by WP_Widget_Recent_Comments in Twenty Ten theme (with modified fonts):

[image]

I'm trying to do it in functions.php of my child theme. I've found that WP create this string there:
\wp-includes\widgets\class-wp-widget-recent-comments.php
148

```
$output .= sprintf(
    _x( '%1$s on %2$s', 'widgets' ),
```

I've googled and tried 100500 different variations of apply_filters in my child theme fuctions.php, eg:

```
apply_filters('widget_text_content', 'replace_text');
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('on','', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

but all of them doesn't work for this widget. At the same time regular apply_filters to 'the_content' filter works alright. Please help :)